# Showing Consecutive Windows on PyQt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

I'm new at PyQt4. My question is very simple: I can't open a password window and, when authenticated, close/hide it and then open a new separate window. Second window vanishes fast. My approach has been this (simplified):

```
import sys, time
from PyQt4 import QtGui

class Window2(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window2, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Window2')
        # ...add the widgets, etc.
        self.show()

class PasswordWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PasswordWindow, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('PasswordWindow')
        self.show()
        # ...Here, I'd input the password, authenticate, etc
        self.hide() 
        w2 = window2()  # go to the true main window

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    pw = PasswordWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it has to do with the `Window2` object being local to the `PasswordWindow.initUI` function. When I replace

```
w2 = Window2()
```

with

```
self.w2 = Window2()
```

I get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear,  w2 gets destroyed when initUi returns.  Doing self.w2 = Window2() assigns w2 to the password window object and thus w2 will exist until the password object is destroyed.

Comment: Thank You, Shrewmouse, I tried to make the program the simplest possible, I can hide the password window and let it be the "parent" object, though that possibly is not very nice-looking code.